# Why is it that for most Bluetooth audio devices, you can't use them while charging?

Tags: bluetooth, speakers

Over the past several years, I've had many small Bluetooth devices. I'm not one to buy many of these and, some how, over the years I've been gifted decent "SWAG", portable speakers and they've all had one thing in common--plug it in to charge, and you can't use the speaker.

Last year, I bought a pair of Skull Candy head phones that were Bluetooth.  I spare the personal anecdotes, but generally speaking, I don't like wireless headphones so there were the first one's I've owned that weren't super-cheap and made by a "named brand".

To my agitation, I found out that even with these, if I plug them in they turn off.  And I mean completely.  They disconnect from my paired device (though they don't unpair) and then when I unplug the charger, they re-connect to my PC.

Why is this a thing and so common?  Again, I'll spare my personal details and preferences, but this is a large part of why I don't like wireless devices--batteries die at the most inconvenient times, but this could be alleviated as a problem if I could at least plug the device in too charge and use it at the same time.  Why is this seemingly not a thing, even with "named brand" devices?

After googling a bit, I see that there are some devices that allow for use and charging, but they are uncommon.  I just want to know, why isn't this a thing?  It seems like it shouldn't be that difficult to engineer into such a simple device.

Comment: Possibly due to safety reasons.

Comment: To prevent you walking around with it plugged-in and snapping the wires because you've forgotten about it being plugged-in. Think about an RC car --> how problematic would that be if it could still drive around whilst being charged. Would that feature be desirable?

Comment: Safety, yes - you don't want something plugged into mains stuck in your ears, there were stories about people dying from that. Also, probably it is a bit simpler in terms of electronics involved - making it cheaper.

Comment: @Andyaka I can't believe that's the right answer.  I use wired speakers more often than not.  In fact, my current headphones also have a wired-in port, I can plug directly into my sending device.  I use to use it until my audio drivers crapped out and I had to get an alternative.  Having a 3-5ft cable attached to your headphones and "forgetting" isn't rational, even for non-headphone speakers.  We've used cables on headphones originally and for decades.  If I don't notice that, it's not the manufacturers problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. ok, I'll accept that idea, but to be honest, 90% of all BT speakers I've owned have been external speakers, not head phones.  Ignoring that I currently use head phones, why is this almost universally true for all BT speakers?

Comment: @RLH I have two BT speakers and couple of devices that can be used as BT speakers - all can be used when charged. OTOH, I also own two pairs of headphones, which cannot.. So my statistic does not support it :)

Comment: It's funny, I get a different impression. The few bluetooth speakers I've used have been able to charge and run at the same time (and I do mean charge, going by their power status indicators, not just run).  I had a bluetooth receiver connected to my hifi that could charge and run at the same time, which was just as well as the quiescent drain on the battery meant it was always flat.  It's only my headphones that can't - and like you I'm a reluctant user, but know that the waterproof bungs on my phone will wear out before the rets of the phone if I open them several times a day

Comment: @Andyaka I'm currently sitting with wired headphones plugged into my PC.  Doing the same with a USB charging cable rather than an audio cable would seem reasonable 
(USB would self-unplug better than the right-angle plug on these).  Indeed there are even wired USB headsets.

Comment: @ChrisH I guess the point Andyaka is making is that the BT headphones are *normally* unplugged, and the user gets used to it, and can forget that it is plugged at the moment, unlike the normally plugged ones.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's a point I can understand, though disagree with, especially as many support an analogue wired mode as well, including my big ones, demonstrating that sometimes-wired is acceptable.  That said I wouldn't trust that design for much - the micro-USB charging cable they came with didn't fit all the way in until I trimmed some plastic implying a distinct lack of care.

Comment: A closely-related further irritation is that I've had phones that will charge other devices out of their USB ports - but you can't top up your headphones while listening through them

Comment: But note that many, even most USB battery packs behave the same.  A few cheap ones will charge and output power at once, but most won't enable their output if they're charging.  Anker [state this explicitly](https://support.anker.com/s/article/Do-Anker-power-banks-support-pass-through-charging) even if their reasoning makes little sense

Comment: Here is an [article](https://voomelody.com/can-we-use-bluetooth-headphones-while-charging-them/) stating few of the reasons. Take it to a limited extent though, as it does not seem to be very  authoritative...

Comment: In my experience you _can_ use most brands while charging...? Damn things run out of batteries all the time so you kind of _have_ to charge them all the time. Why I gave up on wireless long time ago and went for wires instead, good riddance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer definitively for some cases, because I've been involved in the design of the charging scheme for some of these types of products.

There are different schemes for charging.  One charging scheme often called "Power Path" allows for the system to operate during charging even when the battery is very low.  This scheme puts a FET (often called BatFET) in between the charger output and the battery.  When the battery is low, the FET can go into linear mode and regulate the charge current, yet still allow the system to operate from a higher voltage.

Here's an example of the different architectures from [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slyp818/slyp818.pdf?ts=1679500818265&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F):

[image]

You can see that in the power path scheme if the battery voltage is low, the system can still operate if Q2 drops the voltage between the system load and the battery, while regulating the battery charge current .

The other scheme is direct charging where the battery and system are tied together.  When the battery is too low to run the system during charging, the system can't operate.  Often, the system is just locked out until charging is complete so the charging current can be properly regulated.

The power path approach needs the additional FET, which has to be a fairly large device.  It requires additional complexity, back-gate switching for bi-directional current control, and often higher component count.

A bare-bones direct-connected charger IC is substantially cheaper, so in many cases that's the main reason for choosing that architecture and locking out use of the device while charging.  Obviously in some cases there could be other considerations like safety.

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I've been looking for.